# Adding address book in contact page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I want to add an address book in my **contact** page and I want to do that programmatically **i.e** without using `nib files`. Can anyone suggest me a nice tutorial or sample code for that. i have used the codes of the answer given by iPatel and when i am running it is throwing exception and app is getting terminated.
thanks and regards.

Here is the edited code.

```
#import "ContactInfoViewController.h"

@interface ContactInfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation ContactInfoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(gotohomepage:)]autorelease];
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[[picker navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];


picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];


}
- (IBAction)gotohomepage:(id)sender
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
int i;
NSString *strName = @"";
NSString* company = @"";
NSString *address = @"";
NSString *suburb = @"";
NSString *postalcode = @"";
NSString *state = @"";
NSString *country = @"";
NSString *mobile = @"";
NSString *phone = @"";
NSString *emailid = @"";
strName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
company  = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef) person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
NSArray*  allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook,name);
CFRelease(name);

for (i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef record = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty);
    for(CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); i++)
    {
        NSString* HomeLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, i);
        if([HomeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
        {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
            address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey)];
            suburb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey)];
            postalcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey)];
            state = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey)];
            country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict,  kABPersonAddressCountryKey)];
            CFRelease(dict);
        }
        CFRelease(HomeLabel);
    }
    CFRelease(multiValue);
}
CFRelease(allPeople);


ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString* mobileLabel = nil;
for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
{
    mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
    if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
    {
        mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        NSLog(@"phone   %@",mobile);
    }
    else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
    {
        phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        NSLog(@"phone   %@",phone);

        CFRelease(mobileLabel);
        break ;
    }
    CFRelease(mobileLabel);

}
CFStringRef value, label;
ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
if (count == 1)
{
    value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    emailid = (NSString*) value;
    NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
    CFRelease(value);
}
else
{
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
        value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
        if (CFStringCompare(label, kABWorkLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }
        else if(CFStringCompare(label, kABHomeLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }
        CFRelease(label);
        CFRelease(value);
    }
}
CFRelease(multi);
 CFRelease(phones);
CFRelease(addressBook);
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
}
#pragma mark - ABPeopelPickerNavigationController Delegate and DataSource Methods
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownCardViewController didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
return YES;
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController  *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
{
return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Comment: u mean get contact address and add to in your view ???

Comment: i want to create a simple contact page which will contain the details of any person. it should be able to add or remove persons from the list. and contact details should contain all basic info like first name, last name, email, phone no etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT :**

First Add all Delegate and Datasource method in your class **.h file**

```
<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,ABPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

Create `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        [[picker navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
        NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];


        picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
        // Show the picker
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```

Add Following Delegate and DataSource method of `ABPeopelPickerNavigationController`

```
#pragma mark - ABPeopelPickerNavigationController Delegate and DataSource Methods

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownCardViewController didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
{
    return YES;
}
```

please try below code for get all the information of people from phonebook

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    int i;
    NSString *strName = @"";
    NSString* company = @"";
    NSString *address = @"";
    NSString *suburb = @"";
    NSString *postalcode = @"";
    NSString *state = @"";
    NSString *country = @"";
    NSString *mobile = @"";
    NSString *phone = @"";
    NSString *emailid = @"";


    strName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
    CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
    company  = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef) person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);

    NSArray*  allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook,name);
    CFRelease(name);

    for (i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef record = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];

        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        for(CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); i++)
        {
            NSString* HomeLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, i);
            if([HomeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
            {
                CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
                address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey)];
                suburb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey)];
                postalcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey)];
                state = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey)];
                country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey)];

                CFRelease(dict);
            }
            CFRelease(HomeLabel);
        }
        CFRelease(multiValue);
    }
    CFRelease(allPeople);


    ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString* mobileLabel = nil;
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
    {
        mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
        {
            mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSLog(@"phone   %@",mobile);
        }
        else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
        {
            phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSLog(@"phone   %@",phone);

            CFRelease(mobileLabel);
            break ;
        }
        CFRelease(mobileLabel);

    }
    CFStringRef value, label;
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
    if (count == 1)
    {
        value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
        emailid = (NSString*) value;
        NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        CFRelease(value);
    }
    else
    {
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
            value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

            // check for Work e-mail label
            if (CFStringCompare(label, kABWorkLabel, 0) == 0)
            {
                emailid = (NSString*) value;
                NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
            }
            else if(CFStringCompare(label, kABHomeLabel, 0) == 0)
            {
                emailid = (NSString*) value;
                NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
            }

            CFRelease(label);
            CFRelease(value);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(multi);

        }


    CFRelease(phones);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;

}
```

For more information read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html) and [this](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/) tutorial.

**Thanks :)**

Comment: bro errors are not there but when i run it nothing appears on the contact page.. whats the problem?

Comment: Othewise display in console all value display in them?

Comment: i have added all the methods properly.. u just see once and edit the code if possible. add those methods in your code i will see what mistake i have done. sorry for bothering you.. i am just a beginner in this field. hope u understand.

Comment: i tried the edited code. some warnings are there and when i run it and go to contact page its throwing some exception and app is getting terminated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24099/discussion-between-ipatel-and-shanu-singh)