# iOS ABPersonViewController: Returning to app after phone call/message/email

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using an ABPersonViewController and I was wondering if it is possible to return to my application after making a phone call or sending an email/message instead of exiting to the respective native apps.

On the iPhone Contacts app, you can make a phone call by pressing the phone number field. Ending the call automatically takes you back to the contact screen. You can also send an email and message by clicking on the respective fields (though ending the email/message action does not take you back to the Contacts).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uEvAxfa.png]

To be more specific, tapping on "mobile 1 (555) 555-5559" should make a phone call to that number (my app already does that). However, when I end the call, I would like to be directed back to my app and not the native iOS Phone app. I would like similar actions for sending an email and message too.

If this is possible, it would be great if someone could share the solution! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635015/1506363

Comment: I've seen this technique, but I'm not sure if it is possible to implement this with ABPersonViewController?

Comment: why not give it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is possible to return to my application after making a phone call or sending an email/message instead of exiting to the respective native apps.

**AND**

> Ending the call automatically takes you back to the contact screen

**In SHORT :** It is not possible because **Apple/iOS** Does not Provide this type of **Feature**.

Comment: As I indicated in my original post, this feature is actually possible with the current native iOS Contacts app. However, I am having trouble implementing it with ABPersonViewController.

Comment: @Chun-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729959/adding-address-book-in-contact-page/14730304#14730304 for ABPersonViewController